# Symfony passes bad default value to parameter

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

Symfony passes empty value (`""`) to first parameter.

The controller definition:

```
/**
* @Route("/{mediaGenreP}/{mediaLanguageP}/{pageMedia}", name="index", requirements={"mediaGenreP": "\d*", "mediaLanguageP": "\d*"})
*/
public function indexAction($mediaGenreP = null, $mediaLanguageP = null, $pageMedia = 0);
```

or

```
/**
* @Route("/{mediaGenreP}/{mediaLanguageP}/{pageMedia}", name="index", requirements={"mediaGenreP": "\d*", "mediaLanguageP": "\d*"})
*/
public function indexAction($mediaGenreP = 0, $mediaLanguageP = null, $pageMedia = 0);
```

When I access `/` or `//1`, Symfony passes `""` as the value to `mediaGenreP`. It was supposed to be `0` because the default int value is `0`.

Comment: Have your read about [optional route parameters](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/routing/optional_placeholders.html)?

Comment: Yes I do. Have try it by your own? Because with `defaults={"mediaGenreP"=0}` Symfony passes `""` to the parameter.

Comment: Here are the values Symfony passes to the parameters when accessing the link `//2`: `mediaGenreP: "", mediaLanguageP: "2", pageMedia: 0`.

Comment: Where is "default" on your annotation? That why he asked you if you did read the doc... `@Route("/blog/{page}", defaults={"page"=1})`

Comment: @Preciel Read the 2nd comment.

Comment: Didn't see it, sorry. Are all your route parameters optional?

Comment: @Preciel yes they are.

Comment: Have you already try to strongtype your parameter as interger?  This should force symfony to pass integer instead of string